# Modify a sub value of json file using python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to create multiple JSON files with different numbers at specific value, this is my code :

```
import json

json_dict = {
  "assetName": "GhostCastle#",
  "previewImageNft": {
    "mime_Type": "png",
    "description": "#",
    "fileFromIPFS": "QmNuFreEoJy9CHhXchxaDAwuFXPHu84KYWY9U7S2banxFS/#.png",
    "metadataPlaceholder": [
      { 
        "": ""
      }
    ]  
}
}

n = 10
for i in range(1, n+1):
    json_dict["assetName"] = f"GhostCastle{i}"
    json_dict[#What to put here to choose "fileFromIPFS"] = f"QmNuFreEoJy9CHhXchxaDAwuFXPHu84KYWY9U7S2banxFS/{i}.png"
    with open(f"{i}.json", 'w') as json_file:
        #json.dump() method save dict json to file
        json.dump(json_dict, json_file)
```

so What to put to choose "fileFromIPFS" in the second json_dict

Comment: If you want to access the value of `fileFromIPFS` then Just use it as `json_dict['previewImageNft']['fileFromIPFS'] `

Comment: Thank you it's working !